# What is the best method to use ObservableLists for both GUI and background Tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, javafx

SSCCE:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        ListView<Integer> root = new ListView<Integer>();
        ObservableList<Integer> data = Model.getInstance().getData();
        root.setItems(data);

        // A Thread that simulates changes to GUI Observant List.
        Thread populate = new Thread(()->{
            for(int i=0;i<20000;i+=1){
                int finalInstance = i;
                // Changes are done on FXThread
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    data.add(finalInstance);
                });
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });populate.start();
        // Populates at 200 elements/s

        // Server Thread that Sends current status of ObservableList<Integer> data
        Thread server = new Thread(()->{
            try{
                // Server Socket
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555);System.out.println("SERVER ONLINE:");
                while(true){
                    Socket s = ss.accept();
                    // Client Handler Thread to Handle Clients
                    Thread clientHandler = new Thread(()->{
                        try{
                            System.out.println("SERVER CLIENT:"+s);
                            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                            List<Integer> dataCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                            // Get Current Status of data List that is being used in FXThread adn store in dataCopy
                            Semaphore waitForReadToComplete = new Semaphore(0);
                            Platform.runLater(()->{
                                System.out.println("EXPECTED LENGTH: "+data.size());
                                for(Integer a:data){
                                    dataCopy.add(a);
                                    try{
                                        Thread.sleep(5); // Simulate delay while copying large elements
                                    }catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                                }
                                waitForReadToComplete.release(); // Marks Read Operation Complete
                            });
                            waitForReadToComplete.acquire();// Resumes Client Thread
                            oos.writeObject(dataCopy);oos.flush();
                            s.close();
                        }catch (InterruptedException | IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });clientHandler.start();
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });server.start();


        // Client Thread that requests for current status of ObservableList<Integer> data.
        Thread client = new Thread(()->{
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),5555);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                List<Integer> dataCopy;
                dataCopy = (ArrayList<Integer>)ois.readObject();
                s.close();
                System.out.println("ACTUAL LENGTH RECIEVED BY CLIENT "+dataCopy.size());
            }catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });client.start();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}



// Singleton Class with Eager Initialization
class Model{
    static Model onlyInstance = new Model();
    ObservableList<Integer> data = FXCollections.<Integer>observableArrayList();
    public static Model getInstance(){
        return onlyInstance;
    }

    public ObservableList<Integer> getData(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

In this example, I intend to send over the status of the `data` List to a client when it connects to my Server Thread.

The problem is that every time I want to read the `data` List, I need to do it using a `Platform.runLater()` call, whose scheduling is not in my control.

I use a Semaphore to block the Server's Client Handler thread in order to make sure that the complete List is copied and then sent to the client.

As visible, This method makes my client wait for a longer period of time since copying the `data` List is done inside `Platform.runLater()`.

I was wondering if there was a better way to share my `data` List between the FXThread and Background Threads.

EDIT:

Better wording, courtesy of @James_D

I have a model with some (possibly large amount of) data. The model is being updated by a background thread. The server has access to the model and sends the data on demand to network-connected clients. And then there's a UI, which is server-side. And I want the UI to display the current state of the model on the server-side and perform add/remove operations on the data from the UI user.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a delay while copying large elements. You have lists, they contain references to objects. There are no large elements regardless of how large the objects they point at are. Why do you grab a copy of `data` at the time of connection? Did you consider keeping a sharable copy of data up to date?

Comment: The code is not SSCCE without  `"sample.fxml`

Comment: `Model.getInstance().getData();` can be replaced with `new Model().getData();` so it isn't really a singleton. Consider making `Model` thread safe.

Comment: @c0der I removed the dependency on `sample.fxml`.

Comment: @matt I framed it the wrong way, I meant the delay in copying lots of references and not the actual size of the object, sorry about that. I did not consider keeping a sharable up-to-date copy since I required real-time updates and keeping a sharable copy between the FXThread and Background Thread would be the same as just sharing the `data` list. I grab a copy of `data` to send it over the Socket.

Comment: What's the actual requirement here? You have a model with some (possibly large amount of) data. The model is being updated by a background thread. The server has access to the model and sends the data on demand to network-connected clients. And then there's a UI, which is server-side? And you want the UI to display the current state of the model on the server side (i.e. the UI is running in the same JVM as the server)? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes @James_D all of that and the UI can also modify the said data, using `Add/Remove` Operations. As of now, all `read/write` operations on said data is done using `Platform.runLater()` , I was wondering if there's a better way. @c0der introduced a nice approach by using a `unmodifiableObservableList` with Listeners but I'm not sure if that'll hold when the GUI is allowed to change the underlying data as well,i.e , I just can't think of a way to extend that approach to GUI based modifications as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a `Model` shared between the javafx Application, the modifying thread, and the server:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Model model;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        ListView<Integer> listView = new ListView<>();
        ObservableList<Integer> data = listView.getItems();

        model = new Model();

        model.getData().addListener(
                (ListChangeListener<Integer>) listener -> {
                    listener.next();
                    Platform.runLater(()->  data.addAll(listener.getAddedSubList()));
                }
        );

        populate();
        new Server(model, 5555).activate();
        new Client("localhost",5555).activate();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(listView, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void populate() {

        Thread populate = new Thread(()->{
            for(int i=0;i<20000;i+=1){
                model.addData(i);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });populate.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Model{

    private final ObservableList<Integer> data = FXCollections.<Integer>observableArrayList();
    private final ObservableList<Integer> readOnlyData = FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(data);

    synchronized void addData(int i){
        data.add(i);
    }

    public ObservableList<Integer> getData(){
        return readOnlyData;
    }
}
```

The `Server` definition, including `ServerThread` to support multiple clients:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Server {

    private final ExecutorService pool;
    private final List<ServerThread> clients;
    private final int portNumber;
    private  boolean stop;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private final Model model;

    Server(Model model, int portNumber) {
        this.model = model;
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        clients = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void runServer(){

        System.out.println("SERVER: Waiting for client");
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            stop = false;

            while(! stop){//do in loop to support multiple clients
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("SERVER: client connected");
                ServerThread st1 = new ServerThread(model.getData(), clientSocket);
                pool.execute(st1);
                clients.add(st1);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            closeSocket();
        }
    }

    public void stop(){

        for( ServerThread st : clients) {
            st.stopServerTread();
        }
        stop = true;
        pool.shutdown();
        closeSocket();
    }

    public void activate(){
        new Thread(()->runServer()).start();
    }

    private void closeSocket() {

        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private Socket socket = null;
    private  boolean stop;
    private final ObservableList observableList;

    public ServerThread(ObservableList<Integer> observableList ,Socket socket) {
        this.observableList = observableList;
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            stop = false;
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
            String fromClient;
            while(! stop){
                if((fromClient = in.readUTF()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("SERVER: recieved message - " + fromClient);
                    out.writeUTF("Data size is " + observableList.size());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
    }

    void stopServerTread(){
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

And finally the client which requests info from the server:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Client{

    private final  int portNumber;
    private final String hostName;
    private  boolean stop;

    Client(String hostName, int portNumber )  {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
    }

    private void runClient(){
        try {
            stop = false;
            Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

            while (! stop) {
                out.writeUTF("Request Size"); //any not null string to get server response
                String fromServer  = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println(fromServer);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void activate(){
        new Thread(()->runClient()).start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey c0der , thanks for the code. It works perfectly. I read the docs for `ListChangeListener.Change` and had a few questions, (1) Can deletion operations be handled with `getRemoved()`? and (2) If I allow the user to modify the listview using `add/remove` operations, can I propagate these changes back to the `Model` instance?

Comment: @asds_asds I would handle user operations on the data by invoking methods on the model, which would cause your listener to be invoked. `getRemoved()` will give you any removed elements.

Comment: Alright, I'll modify my code based on what @c0der wrote and modify using methods on the model. Ofc, methods on the model will do what's needed. They'll trigger the listeners which will then add or remove elements. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you could change is the order that your submitting your tasks. Instead of starting the client thread, then calling run later and waiting for the response. Just call Platform.runLater, populate the copy and then start the client thread. Now there is no reason for a semaphore.

```
    // Immediately following the accept.
    Platform.runLater(()->{
        System.out.println("EXPECTED LENGTH: "+data.size());
        List<Integer> dataCopy = new ArrayList<>(data);
        Thread clientHandler = new Thread(()->{
            try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()) ) {
                System.out.println("SERVER CLIENT:"+s);
                oos.writeObject(dataCopy);
                oos.flush();
            }catch (InterruptedException | IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         });
         clientHandler.start();
     });
```

Creating a new thread each time should be replaced with an executor service of some sort. Depending on the task, consider using javafx.concurrent [Task](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). Your server loop could be a task for example.

It's possible to expose an view of the data backing your observable list.

```
List<String> cowal = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableList(cowal);
List<String> dataCopy = Collections.unmodifiableList(cowal);
```

I made it a copy on write array list so you can iterate over the view without getting a CCME. I called it a dataCopy to be consistent with the previous naming, but it is a view of the data.

Also, as a matter of taste, instead of `});server.start();` create a new line to call `server.start();`

Comment: Isn't this the same performance-wise? You make a copy of references and then ask another thread to transmit them. I made a copy of the references and blocked the original thread while it was being made. I do agree that I should've just passed `data` into the constructor. However when I copy lots of references, then a considerable delay occurs, I was just wondering if it was possible to remove this delay. I guess every time I need to read a data item which is being used to form the GUI, I'll have to use `Platform.runLater()`, no way around that.

Comment: @asds_asds the advantage of this method is that you don't have a thread waiting for the semaphore to return. It will work better with an executorservice because you're not tying up a thread unecessarily. This prepares the data, then sends it to be processed in another thread. How many references are you copying? It seems odd that you would have such a large collection that the copying time is considerable, but it still needs to be observed by the gui. Another way to do it would be to keep  an update-to-date copy, Observables will notify you when they change.

Comment: There are about 1e5 references. I understand that the semaphore ties up a thread unnecessarily, I'll rectify that part. I'm familiar with observables but I'm new to the up to date copy part, can you link something or give a few words on that 

Comment: @asds_asds I pretty simply mean, having a listener and then in the listener, updating your copy. Can you make an SCCE? I don't have a problem accessing an observable list from another thread. Beyond normal multithreaded collection access. Also, I added in the example a way to view the backing data.